# QFile atEnd: how to reset "atEnd"?

Tags: qt, qfile

After open a text file, I read all with:

```
QFile MyFile("myfile.txt);
MyFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QTextStream in (&MyFile);
while (!in.atEnd())
{
 (do something);
}
MyFile.close();
```

When I recall my function, the "while" loop appears as at its end, so none of the function placed in it are done.
Is it a way to re-initialize "atEnd", in such a way I can re-enter in the "while" loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QTextStream has a [seek](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#seek) function, allowing the position of the stream to be set.
Calling

```
in.seek(0)
```

will set the stream to the beginning of the file.

However, if the code in the question is in a function, the QFile and QTextStream should be deleted when the function exists, since they're created on the stack, so there may something else going on here, which the question is omitting.

Comment: Also using "in.seek(0)", while loop still continue to not be evaluated a second time if it has been completed.
Function placed inside search a string in text file; if the string is found, this is detected and placed in a QLabel; if not, the test file is read from its beginning to the end, warning the user about no correpsonding text has been found. Only in this last case, a new enter in while loop doesn't come (Analizing bool "in.atEnd" it appears always as true (file already at end)

Comment: I suspect the problem lies outside the minimal example code you've shown.

Comment: you're right, because before the loop there was a filename editation that modified the filename itself; so at the second loop passage, the read file wasn't the same. Anyway I had to use "while (line.isNull())" instead of "while(in.atEnd)". Problem solved.